# Index Match in R

Tags: r

I searched how to replicate index match in R and found a solution that worked for smaller data sets, but would not work with two data frames with (a)daily interest rate history for multiple swap rates for 5 years as well as (b) individual loan detail with 200,000+ records.  I manipulated the result in excel via index(match) but wanted to learn the efficient way to do it in R.

Here is is in a nutshell:

```
RateData <- data.frame(Date = c("2018-01-01","2018-01-05","2018-01-08","2018-01-17"), 
               Threeyr = c(1.25,1.27,1.29, 1.30), 
               Fiveyr = c(2.3,2.31,2.34, 2.4),
               Tenyr = c(2.8,2.89,2.75, 2.6),
               PRIME = c(4.0,4,4, 4.25))

LoanData <- data.frame(OriginationDate = c("2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-05",
                                       "2018-01-08","2018-01-08","2018-01-17"),
                   LNTYPE = c(83,101,115,83,83,105,115),
                   PriceIndex = c('Threeyr','Fiveyr','PRIME','Threeyr','Threeyr','Fiveyr','PRIME'))
```

I want to match/join the data so that only the rate for the particular origination date from the appropriate index in inputted to a new column in LoanData.  Again I tried a suggestion from another post using spread() / gather() and works for this small example but uses too much memory for my full dataset.

I tried below but gives me a matrix result

```
LoanData$Rate <- RateData[match(LoanData$OriginationDate,RateData$Date),
                      match(LoanData$PriceIndex,colnames(RateData))]
```

How to I get desired result of:

```
LoanData1 <- data.frame(OriginationDate = c("2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-05",
                                       "2018-01-08","2018-01-08","2018-01-17"),
                   LNTYPE = c(83,101,115,83,83,105,115),
                   PriceIndex = c('Threeyr','Fiveyr','PRIME','Threeyr','Threeyr','Fiveyr','PRIME'),
                   Rate = c(1.25,2.30,4,1.27,1.29,2.34,4.25))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You should use the `merge` functionality see https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html EDIT: would have to `melt` the RateData first to get the tenor column names as values within rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, it's just that you have to use a matrix to subscript along multiple dimensions, else you get a product of the combinations. Correct is:

```
LoanData$Rate <- RateData[cbind(
  match(LoanData$OriginationDate, RateData$Date),
  match(LoanData$PriceIndex, colnames(RateData))
)]
```

Comment: Nice!   Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You could use reshape2 library:

```
library(reshape2)
x00=melt(RateData)
LoanData$Rate=sapply(1:nrow(LoanData),function(x) filter(x00,Date==LoanData[x,1]&variable==LoanData[x,3])$value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trial:

```
library(data.table)

#Find all the names in Ratedata that match the Priceindex per date

 A=setDT(LoanData)[,.(names(RateData[-1])%in%PriceIndex,1:4),keyby=OriginationDate]

 #Rearrange the data,then only take the Rates that you need
 B=dcast(A,OriginationDate~V2,value.var = "V1")[-1]*RateData[-1]

#Reshape it to the required order after removing the rows whereby the rate is 0
 data.frame(na.omit(`is.na<-`(C<-melt(cbind(RateData[1],B),1),C==0)),LoanData$LNTYPE)

         Date variable value LoanData.LNTYPE
1  2018-01-01        1  1.25              83
2  2018-01-05        1  1.27             101
3  2018-01-08        1  1.29             115
5  2018-01-01        2  2.30              83
7  2018-01-08        2  2.34              83
13 2018-01-01        4  4.00             105
16 2018-01-17        4  4.25             115
```